# How to write SQL statement to automatically use specified date in BETWEEN statement?

Tags: sql

This SQL code I'm working with is not my own, and the person who did create it no longer is around. I have a SELECT statement that uses WHERE and BETWEEN to set some parameters. My question is how can I write the statement to include a specified date and for said date to automatically update.

I've tried a few different methods for what I thought would work. I'm not very proficient in SQL.

```
WHERE CORDT BETWEEN 'CURDATE()' AND '#CURRENT_TIMESTAMP#'
```

I expect the data I retrieve to be between the date of first of the month and the last day of the month.

EDIT: The date is only thing Im concerned with, not a time. But it also has to be in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: Which database are you using Oracle, MSSQL, Postgres, other?

Comment: Its a very old DB that is stored on some IBM machines. I couldn't tell you what it actually is. The original query was written for a program called "ShowCase" which normally prompts the user for a start and end date, hence those parameters. The new query I'm trying to run does not have that same prompt. So the dates have to be entered manually or automatically by SQL. I know that is vague but I really do not have more information.

Comment: It sounds like you have some program connecting to the database. Please show us the code where the program does this, so we can see which DBMS this probably is.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want your query to select the current month (e.g. right now June 1 to June 30, 2019)? And why are you talking about a data format? In SQL a date has no format. Only when showing dates there would be the need to display it in some format the user understands, but this is usually done in the program then, not in SQL.

Comment: Yes, and because a date written as mm-dd-yyyy or mm.dd.yyyy will not work in the query. And I did not know that

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in SQL server, you can create your start and end dates with the following:

```
DECLARE @StartOfMonth DateTime =  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
DECLARE @NextMonth DateTime = DATEADD(month, 1, @StartOfMonth)
```

You can then use between against those. Since the @NextMonth variable starts at midnight exactly, you will likely never match against that... So it should cover everthing up until that date as long as you are matching on datetime and not date. Another option would be to do one more bit of dateadd math where you subtract a second from @NextMonth.

Comment: the program I am using is called "DataGuru", will this work in there?

Comment: The detail I gave you was specific for use in a SQL query construct / procedure. In my case, SQL server / TSQL.

Comment: "TOKEN DATE TIME WAS NOT VALID. " is the error I received.

Comment: Yeah, DataGuru is probably a visual query designer window tool. We would need to know what the actual Database system is.

Comment: I think the system is called AS400